# How is my nib file get loaded without calling initWithNibName?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I instantiated my view controller using the basic init:

`MyViewController *myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];`

For some reason, it is automatically loading `MyViewController.xib` without me ever calling `initWithNibName` anywhere. How is this possible?? Is this something new introduced in iOS 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not new, the `init` method just check if there is an `nib` with the same name as your class.

Comment: So there is really no reason to use `initWithNibName` unless for some reason your nib is named differently?

Comment: Yes it should, but can't tell you from which version of iOS this will work, I've used it in iOS 4 and 5.